# Get total time of Execution for Extent Report

Tags: c#, testing, automation, extentreports

I want to get the total time of execution for my TestSuite. Iam using Extent reports and want to get the execution time from extent report object. how it can be done.

Iam expecting the total time taken for the execution.

Comment: You can record start time before call `TestSuite` and end time after finish calling. And then you can calculate time difference between them.